# Core graphics is there a way to do fill and stroke in a single command

Tags: objective-c, macos, quartz-graphics

I am building a path with a series of CGContextAdd.. Commands and then I want to fill and stroke the path but if I fill the path I currently have to recreate the path I want to stroke it as well is there a way to do both in one hit avoiding having to create the path twice .
Christian Arild Stær Andersen

Answer (score 2):

Call [`CGContextDrawPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextDrawPath) using `kCGPathFillStroke` to fill and stroke the same path.

```
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```